# How to get e-mail IDs of all the users in AWS Cognito user pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to have a set of email IDs of all the users in the AWS Cognito user pool of my application.

Answer (score 1):

AWS CLI is very helpful in these scenario. You can use

```
aws cognito-idp list-users
```

You may chose the attributes to get and further filter it as required. Further details available in the documentation here.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/list-users.html

Answer (score -3):

This is possible,

Kindly go to users and groups section in Cognito User Pool. Press Import Users button and download the csv template for user upload. Populate the csv with all data to be imported to AWS Cognito user Pool.

You are done.